# Could not find or load main class in face recognition using opencv in java

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv, netbeans, face-detection

I am trying to implement face recognition using opencv.I am getting the error : **Could not find or load main class in face recognition using opencv in java.**  I have tried this on netbeans and eclipse.

following is the code:

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfRect;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier;

public class DetectFace {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    System.out.println("\nRunning FaceDetector");

    CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier(DetectFace.class.getResource("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml").getPath());
    Mat image = Imgcodecs
            .imread(DetectFace.class.getResource("shekhar.JPG").getPath());

    MatOfRect faceDetections = new MatOfRect();
    faceDetector.detectMultiScale(image, faceDetections);

    System.out.println(String.format("Detected %s faces", faceDetections.toArray().length));

    for (Rect rect : faceDetections.toArray()) {
        Imgproc.rectangle(image, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height),
                new Scalar(0, 255, 0));
    }

    String filename = "ouput.png";
    System.out.println(String.format("Writing %s", filename));
    Imgcodecs.imwrite(filename, image);
}
}
```

Comment: what is the complete error?

Comment: just could not find and load main class java

Comment: that's not complete .post the full error

Comment: i am getting only this message in eclipse console

Comment: `Could not find or load main class yyy` what is the class name ?

Comment: I ran javac DetectFace.java it came up with error that files have not been imported

Comment: did you add opencv jar files to classpath ??

Comment: how to do that. please help me

Comment: if you use netbeans add them to library of your project

Comment: yeah I have already done that